# New review gives a too-generic error message when out of delete votes

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-delete, alerts

While reviewing [low quality posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/community/low-quality-posts), the message given when you vote to delete when out of votes is too generic.

[image: An error occurred when deleting this post. Please try again.]

It should probably say that the limit for votes to delete has been reached, or (even better) it should not show further posts to delete when the limit has been reached, in the same way it happens when you reach the limit for the votes to close.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific error message is shown now:

> [image]